# how to pass post variable to object (php7)

Tags: php

This seems straightforward but I'm having trouble getting this to work. I'm using a library which has the following line to submit an order:

```
$order = $api->post('/orders', get_order_data());
```

I'm trying to pass the following array to $api>post.

The array looks like this (values from $_POST):

```
$order_data = array(
    'productId' => $productid,
    'pageCount' => $pagecount,
    'quantity' => $quantity,
    'files' => array(                     
        'content' => $file
    )
    );
```

The get_order_data function looks like this

```
function get_order_data($array)
{
  $item = $array;     
}
```

To submit the the request I would like to pass the $order_data array to the following line:

```
$order = $api->post('/orders', get_order_data());
```

The following obviously doesn't work (just put it there hopefully clarify what I'm trying to do) which is trying to pass $order_data to $api->post using PHP7

```
$order = $api->post('/orders', get_order_data($order_data));
```

How can I make $order_data accessible to $api->post ?

Comment: Any reason why you can't pass `$order_data` directly? Why does it have to go through `get_order_data`? Second, if you want `get_order_data` to return any content, you have to call `return <content>`. And if `get_order_data` is suppoed to return `$order_data` - where does that data come from inside the function?

Comment: In the original example the order array is inside the get_order_data() function like so:  get_order_data()  { array(
    'productId' => "...",
    'pageCount' => "...",
    'quantity' => "...",
    'files' => array(                     
        'content' => "..."
    )
    );
}

Comment: Can you edit that ```get_order_data()``` function?  Just ```return($array)``` from there and everything will work.

Comment: You are not returning anything from the get_order_data function!?

Comment: @MatsLindh I ended up passing the array directly as suggested by you.

Comment: "The following obviously doesn't work" — Could you please explain why? It's by no means obvious. To pass function parameters you do include them inside the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, the final soultion was to remove the `get_order_data()` function, and provide `$order_data` directly to `$api->post()` method.

Here's the code:

```php
$order = $api->post('/orders', $order_data);
```

Comment: Your $item does not make sense in your get_order_data function either :-) (It does not do anything)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld that's what the code looks like in the example provided in their docs though, which was the way I tried it initially, I accidentally omitted the 'return $array' in my post. Somehow though it just didn't work doing it that way. I ended up passing the arrays directly. As you also said, the function itself doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
function get_order_data($array)
{
  $item = processThisArray($array);
  $item = //do some other stuff with that array
  return $item;   //return the item so that it's an input in ->post()
}
```